# Activity view model recreates on rotation

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

When I rotate my phone constructor of my MainViewModel calls all the time!

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public MainViewModel onCreateViewModel() {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel.class);
    }
```

BaseActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    performInjection();
    performDataBinding();
}

private void performDataBinding() {
    viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, setLayoutId());
    this.viewModel = viewModel == null ? onCreateViewModel() : viewModel;
    viewDataBinding.setVariable(setBindingVariable(), viewModel);
    viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

MainViewModel constructor:

```
@Inject
MainViewModel(ErrorHandler errorHandler, Router router, TradeInfoInteractor getTradeInfoUseCase) {
    super(errorHandler);
    Log.d(TAG, "constructor");
    this.router = router;
    this.getTradeInfoUseCase = getTradeInfoUseCase;

    init();
}
```

Log on recreation:

> 05-30 20:48:45.046 21513-21513/merseyside.com.cripto D/MainViewModel:
>   constructor
>   05-30 20:48:49.566 21513-21513/merseyside.com.cripto
>   D/MainViewModel: constructor

Whats wrong with that? In documentation said

> "// Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's
>   onCreate() method.
>
> // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity."

Comment: Are you using fragment or Conductor library?

Comment: I use cicerone library for navigation.